# ProcessingJS changing line opacity

Tags: javascript, processing

I'm a beginner to ProcessingJS/JS and I can't seem to get this to work. I'm using processingjs to create circles and lines. On the same class that creates the circles I have the following two functions:

```
void showCompanyLines() {
    if (createdLines == false) {
        createdLines = true;
        rawData['company_partners'].forEach(function(partner) {
            stroke( "#000000", myLinesOpacity);
            var partnerInfo = circlesInfo[companyBubbleIds[partner]];
            var partnerX = partnerInfo[0];
            var partnerY = partnerInfo[1];
            var myLocationX = posFinalX;
            var myLocationY = posFinalY;
            line(posFinalX, posFinalY, partnerX, partnerY);
        });
    }
}

void hideCompanyLines() {
    myLinesOpacity = 0;
}
```

The variable myLinesOpacity is global. If possible I'd like to make it an instance variable, but that can come later.

My only question is why the hideCompanyLines isn't working.

Cheers!

Edit: After making the following changes to the code above:

```
void showCompanyLines() {
    if (!createdLines) {
        for (var j = 0; j < rawData['company_partners'].length; j++)
        {
            partner = rawData['company_partners'][j];
            var partnerInfo = circlesInfo[companyBubbleIds[partner]];
            var partnerX = partnerInfo[0];
            var partnerY = partnerInfo[1];
            var myLocationX = posFinalX;
            var myLocationY = posFinalY;
            var cl = new CompanyLine(partnerX, partnerY, myLocationX, myLocationY, 255);
            companyLines.add(cl);// = cl;
            numLines += 1;
        }
    }
    draw();
}

void hideCompanyLines() {
    createdLines = false;
    for( int i=0; i < companyLines.size(); i++) {
        companyLines.get(i).setOpacity(0);
    }
    draw();
}


class CompanyLine {
    int opacity;
    int x, y, w, z;

    CompanyLine(_x, _y, _w, _z, _opacity) {
        this.x = _x;
        this.y = _y;
        this.w = _w;
        this.z = _z;
        this.opacity = _opacity;
    }

    void setOpacity(op) {
        this.opacity = op;
    }

    boolean update() {
        if (this.opacity == 0) {return false;}
    }

    void display() {
        noFill();
        stroke( "#000000", this.opacity);
        line(x, y, w, z);
        console.log ('displaying with this opacity' + this.opacity)
   }
}
```

I still get the same error. Basically when showCompanyLines is called, the lines are created, then when hideCompanyLines is called they are not made invisible (setting opacity to 0).

I don't really know what else I can try - it has to be some sort of mistake on my part on ProcessingJS's logic.

Cheers.

Comment: What do you mean by "it isn't working". What exactly is happening?

Comment: Hi Nicolas, I made some changes to the code and added some explanation to it. Basically the lines are being created but when I set opacity = 0 they are not made invisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Actually, your problem lies somewhere else. I whipped up the following program in ProcessingJS and it works without a problem. Check it out and compare it with yours and ask more questions here:

```
int opacity = 100;

void setup()
{
  stroke("#000000", opacity);
  strokeWeight(10);

}

void draw()
{
  background(255);
  stroke("#000000", opacity);
  line(0,height/2,width,height/2);
  noLoop();
}

void mouseOver()
{
  opacity = 30;
  loop();
}

void mouseOut()
{
  opacity = 100;
  loop();
}
```

Comment: @EduardoS. What's with the multiple calls to `draw()` in each method? You said they were called using the mouseOver method? Also, make sure the display() method is called in your draw() method. Otherwise mouseOver isn't going to work. More could would of course be more helpful.

Comment: I'm creating an animation initially to set up the canvas and the geometric objects, then I call noLoop. On mouse over, I draw lines connecting some circles set up from the initial animation, when the user mouse overs one of them. I want the lines to disappear as the user removes the mouse from over the circle.

Comment: Still no go - my draw() function calls the display() function correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I'm a bit stumped as to how to fix this I'll probably just refactor the object holding the two functions above and hopefully it will work. Thanks man.

Comment: once you call noLoop() you need to then call loop() not draw(). Check this out: http://processingjs.org/reference/loop_/

Comment: @EduardoS. Check my edit to see how you may add `loop()` to your mouseOver and mouseOut.

Comment: Yep, I modified the functions to remove the noLoop so that I didn't need to call loop/redraw and still no go. Here's the entire code I'm using, for the canvas: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/28f4bf74a7c0439f3ad7

Comment: Alright. Hopefully you can figure it out but leave a comment here if you're still stumped.

Comment: Check out my previous comment, with the entire file location. The functions are being correctly called, it's just not being drawn correctly :/ P.S. some of the code is bad, since I'm just throwing stuff on the wall and hoping some of it sticks. Again, first time working on ProcessingJS :p

Comment: @EduardoS. Are you using Processing PDE (in JavaScript mode)? Your code is throwing a lot of errors. But most importantly, `_circleIndex` is not declared anywhere? The problem is Processing, a lot of the times, doesn't throw errors, it runs but doesn't run properly even if something completely unrelated is off.

Comment: Thanks! _circleIndex is just a local variable. I'll check out PDE and hopefully I can fix this tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are doing exactly... **but** most code (including processing.js) is read from top to bottom, so when you look for `myLinesOpacity`, it is actually not declared yet.

Please tell me if this does not solve it.

Comment: myLinesOpacity is a global variable declared on one of the first lines. It's a huge file (800+ lines of code) so I only showed the two immediately most relevant functions. I think I should add that these two functions are called from a mouseOver trigger - and they are being called (console.log shows them being correctly called).